# Defining an array within a class in php

Tags: php

I have the following array  in php

```
   $criteria = array();
     $criteria['x'] = array();
     $criteria['y'] = array();
     $criteria['z'] = array();
```

I also have a class defined in php with property xyz

```
   $screenerItem = new \StdClass();
   $screenerItem->xyz =0;
```

How can i make my array $criteria as a part of my screenerItem class  property?

I tried this but didnt work,can someone help me out to know what is wrong with this syntax:

```
   $screenerItem->$criteria = array();
   $screenerItem->$criteria['x'] = array();
   $screenerItem->$criteria['y'] = array();
   $screenerItem->$criteria['z'] = array();
```

Comment: `Can i do something like` Try and find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Nahid suggested you can fill your class poperty in constructor.
Another way (if your class property is public) is:

```
$criteria_array = array(/* your array here */);
$screenerItem->criteria = $criteria_array;
// Notice that I don't use $ in front of criteria as it's class property.
```

And of course your attemp is legal too:

```
// Once again no $ before criteria
$screenerItem->criteria = array();
$screenerItem->criteria['x'] = array();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class MyClass{
    public $criteria=array();

    function __construct(){
        $this->criteria=array(
            'x'=>array(),
            'y'=>array(),
            'z'=>array()
            );
    }
}


$screenItem=new MyClass;
```

or You may use this convenction

```
class MyClass{
    public $criteria=array();

    function __construct($array){
        $this->criteria=$array;
    }
}


$data=array(
    'x'=>array(),
    'y'=>array(),
    'z'=>array()
);

$screenItem=new MyClass($data);
```

Comment: rather than assigning the array through a constructor ,can i do property assignemnt in php like $screenItem=new MyClass()  ;$screenItem->$criteria['x']== array();

Comment: follow @u_mulder comment